# Ansible win_file module register results

Tags: ansible

I am using the win_file Ansible module to create directories and files on Windows 2012 R2 servers. I want to register the results of the win_file task but I can't get it to work.

For example this playbook...

```
---
- hosts: windows_server

  gather_facts: no

    - name: create directory on remote windows server
      win_file:
        path: 'c:\temp}'
        state: directory
        register: task_results
        debug: var=task_results
```

...does not print the results of the task.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your playbook syntax is flawed... Try this:

```
---
- hosts: windows_server
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: create directory on remote windows server
      win_file:
        path: 'c:\temp'
        state: directory
      register: task_results
    - debug: var=task_results
```

`register` is a part of task not module's parameter, so it should be with the same indentation.
`debug` is a new task, so it should be another item in a list.
Also there is not `tasks` keyword in your example.